# Form To Send Email, Android

Tags: android, email, android-intent

This subject is well documented here and on the internet but I am still having an issue with this, have tried various code.

My code looks fine but no action is taking place when the Send button is pressed.

I have added the ReportProblemMail activity to my Manifest file, am i missing any permissions?

Your help is very much appreciated.

**reportproblem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="To : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/to_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subject : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/subject_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Message : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_email_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ReportProblemMail.java**

```
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;

        public class ReportProblemMail extends Activity {

            Button mSendButton;
            EditText mTo;
            EditText mSubject;
            EditText mMessage;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.reportproblem);

                mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email_button);
                mTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to_edit_text);
                mSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject_edit_text);
                mMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_edit_text);

                mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                      String to = mTo.getText().toString();
                      String subject = mSubject.getText().toString();
                      String message = mMessage.getText().toString();

                      Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                      email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
                      email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                      email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

                      //prompts email client only
                      email.setType("message/rfc822");

                      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

ReportProblemMail.java

With toast

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              String to = mTo.getText().toString();
              String subject = mSubject.getText().toString();
              String message = mMessage.getText().toString();
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="burger.van"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="burger.van.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


            </intent-filter>



        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="burger.van.MainActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="burger.van.AboutActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="burger.van.SubmitVanActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="burger.vanlocator.ReportProblemActivity" >
        </activity>



        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="burger.van.ReportProblemMail" >
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did your button handle the click ? If you display a Toast in OnClickListener it works ?
I don't see error in your code...
You don't need to add permission because "Although your application is leveraging messaging capabilities on the device, it is not required to have any such permissions. This is because the application is not directly sending messages itself."

Comment: you are testing in emulator or real device?

Comment: Your code works just fine on my end. I suggest for you to try rebuilding your project or do some sync.

Comment: @AdrienCerdan I added a toast but it does not seem to register.

Comment: Ok, now try to add to your button in Xml (android:onClick="sendEmail") and write a method public void sendEmail (View v) {  //put your Toast here   }

Comment: @KaHeL I presume you mean Cleaning the project.

Comment: @TheWelshOne oh sorry about that, does that ring something else? hahaha! Well rebuild project is the term used for android studio and yes it's the same thing. :)

Comment: As you can tell I'm a typical newbie. lol

Comment: haha! same here. Anyway I tried your code a moment ago without changing anything, set up the email then run. Works just fine using emulator (genymotion). It just prompt on what email to use->review email->send. Which is why I'm suggesting for you to clean the project. Anyway can you please add the manifest that you currently had as well as the logs?

Comment: @AdrienCerdan No toast is being displayed on button press. :-(

Comment: The odd thing is, I;ve created a new project with the email code and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I have solved this. I would like the To: field to display a specific email set by myself. How is this achieved? Thanks